# Rollback stored procedure call not working

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to nest a stored procedure call into a MySQL transaction created from a PHP script and rollback the modifications done inside the procedure in case some errors happen in my php script after the SP call.

```php
//Create a new transaction
$pdo->beginTransaction();

//Build and execute the procedure call request
$request = "CALL my_proc(...)";
$pdo->query($request);

//Rollback the transaction
$pdo->rollBack();
```

After the rollback I expect all changes done in DB to be cancelled but all the changes are actually commited.